# While using nostra13 universalimageloader some of the images are not loaded in the GridView?

Tags: android

While using nostra13 universalimageloader some of the images are not loaded in GridView? And the url is deformed as shown in the logcat below (%20%20 is added after some url):

```
http://www.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/waller/WALLPAPER/URL_THUMB/0.jpg%20%20
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/waller/WALLPAPER/URL_THUMB/0.jpg%20%20

at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.URLConnectionImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.ImageDownloader.getStream
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.saveImageOnDisc
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:204)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
at java.lang.Thread.run
http://www.messina-test.com/waller/WALLPAPER/URL_THUMB/0.jpg%20%20
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.messina-test.com/waller/WALLPAPER/URL_THUMB/0.jpg%20%20
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.URLConnectionImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.ImageDownloader.getStream
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.saveImageOnDisc
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run
```

Comment: It seems your URL is wrong. Did you check it on a web browser?

Comment: %20%20 is the Uri code for two spaces - maybe Uri decode and then use .trim() on the string then encode again? (I'm assuming you need the url encoded)

Comment: But only for some of the images i am getting this %20%20.

Comment: Yes the URL is working on web browser but only when i remove %20%20.